# Add own scss files to the appName-all.scss

Tags: extjs, sass, sencha-cmd

In scss I would usually add other scss files using the `@import` command.
With sencha cmd the SCSS file for my ExtJS app is generated.

Where and how do I add custom styles which then should be compiled into the app-all.css?

I don't want to create a custom theme (because I think that's an overkill)
I am using the default Classic theme, ExtJS 4.2 with Sencha Cmd 3.1.2

I see `$include` variables in the generated app-all.scss but there are no @imports for my custom scss files

**generated appName-all.scss**

```
...
$include-ext-window-messagebox: true;
$include-ext-window-window: true;
$include-appname-app-application: true;
$include-appname-controller-customer: true;
$include-appname-view-listings-index: true;
...
@import '../../../packages/ext-theme-classic/sass/var/window/MessageBox';
@import '../../../packages/ext-theme-classic/sass/var/window/Window';
...
@import '../../../packages/ext-theme-classic/sass/src/window/MessageBox';
@import '../../../packages/ext-theme-classic/sass/src/window/Window';
...
```

I've put my custom scss files into the existing `appName/sass/src` folder like this:

`appname/view/listings/Index.scss`

Unfortunately this seems to be ignored, when executing `sencha app build`..
How do I configure Sencha Cmd to include my custom scss files when generating `appname-all.scss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow.. just read my own question and had the idea that actually my folder structure is not really the same as extjs native structure (`theme/sass/src` vs `sass/src/appName`)

moving my `Index.scss` to `appName/sass/src/view/listing/Index.scss` solved the problem totally :)

**new appName-all.scss after sencha app build**

```
/* including package appName */
$branchenbuchAdmin-resource-path: 'images' !default;
$relative-image-path-for-uis: $appName-resource-path;
@import '../../../apps/appName/sass/src/view/listings/Index';
```

Loving it :)